# Filter Empty JsonPayload from GCP logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

We have a service which logs empty line. However, in GCP logs it is coming as empty jsonPayload

```
insertId: jksj3z7vr05sj
jsonPayload: {
}
```

I want to exclude such logs. Tried following queries individully

```
jsonPayload.field = NULL_VALUE
NOT jsonPayload.message = ""
NOT jsonPayload.message = "\n"
```

None of above worked.

Official docs:

1. https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language

Comment: I can think of only one (limited) way that you could do this and that would be to check for the existence of a `jsonPayload` field that is guaranteed to always be present in every other log (perhaps timestamp|ts?). `{}` isn't null, it's the empty object.

Comment: @DazWilkin tried `jsonPayload.message: {}` one as well, this wasn't working

Comment: Yes, apologies if I was unclear, you can't test for `{}`. It's an empty object and there's no syntax to support it. What I meant was something of the form `jsonPayload:*
NOT jsonPayload.ts:*` (contains a `jsonPayload` but doesn't include a `jsonPayload.ts`). The challenge with this is (a) I don't know whether that supports `jsonPayload: {}` as I have none; (b) it requires that any non-empty `jsonPayload` contains `ts` field. You could also use `msg` or `message` if you are strict about including those fields.

Comment: Did the comment of DazWilkin help you with your issue? Did you try another way to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

As per [dazwilkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/609290/dazwilkin)'s comment, this worked for me:

```
NOT jsonPayload.message:*
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a universal solution:

```
-(jsonPayload:*)
```